# Hall conductivity versus isotropy

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, magnetic-fields, quantum-hall-effect

It is known that the Hall conductivity of a two-dimensional system in magnetic field is antisymmetric:
$$
\sigma_{xy}=-\sigma_{yx}.
$$
However the conductivity tensor, being a current response function, should obey some general symmetry properties. G. Giuliani and G. Vignale in "[Quantum theory of the electron liquid](https://books.google.ru/books?id=kFkIKRfgUpsC&lpg=PA145&vq=decomposed%20into%20longitudinal&hl=ru&pg=PA145#v=onepage&q&f=false)" (2005) write on page 145:

> First of all, the homogeneity and isotropy of the system ensure that
>   the tensor $\chi^J_{\alpha\beta}(\vec{q},\omega)$ can be decomposed
>   into longitudinal and transverse components, relative to the direction
>   of $\vec{q}$, each depending only on the magnitude of $\vec{q}$. In
>   other words, the current induced by a purely longitudinal vector
>   potential is purely longitudinal, and that induced by a purely
>   transverse vector potential is purely transverse. More formally, one
>   can write 
>   $$
> \chi^J_{\alpha\beta}(\vec{q},\omega)=\chi_L(q,\omega)\frac{q_\alpha
> q_\beta}{q^2}+\chi_T(q,\omega)\left(\delta_{\alpha\beta}-\frac{q_\alpha q_\beta}{q^2}\right), $$ where $\chi_L$ and $\chi_T$ are the
>   current–current response functions in the longitudinal and transverse
>   channels respectively

Indeed, this property is consistent with the isotropy of space: if we perform a rotation of a coordinate system using the matrix
$$
\Lambda=\left(\begin{array}{rr}\cos\varphi&\sin\varphi\\-\sin\varphi&\cos\varphi\end{array}\right),
$$
then the two-component vectors transform as $\mathbf{j}'=\Lambda \mathbf{j}$, $\mathbf{E}'=\Lambda \mathbf{E}$, $\mathbf{q}'=\Lambda \mathbf{q}$. Thus from the definitions of the conductivity tensors $\mathbf{j}=\hat\sigma(\mathbf{q})\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{j}'=\hat\sigma(\mathbf{q}')\mathbf{E}'$ we find the property
$$
\hat\sigma(\Lambda\mathbf{q})=\Lambda\hat\sigma(\mathbf{q})\Lambda^+,
$$
which is consistent with the longitudinal-transverse decomposition.

This decomposition implies a symmetric nondiagonal conductivity 
$$
\sigma_{xy}=\sigma_{yx}=[\sigma_L(q)-\sigma_T(q)]\frac{q_xq_y}{q^2}.
$$
The Hall conductivity obviously does not satisfy this requirement: it is antisymmetric and does not have an angular dependence $\propto q_xq_y/q^2$ at $q\rightarrow0$.

**So why does the Hall conductivity disobey the isotropy relation? Does a magnetic field break isotropy of space?**

Comment: Does a magnetic field break isotropy of space? -> Obviously yes.

Comment: @FraSchelle In my question, I'm considering a 2D system in the $(x,y)$ plane with the magnetic field in the $z$ direction, so how does this field break isotropy in the $(x,y)$ plane?